# Concerning the default coloring made by Plot3D in 10.4

Tags: plotting, color, mesh

Recently, I have installed **Mathmatica** 10.4, but I found out that when I use `Plot3D`, it gives me a mesh. In order to add color, I have to explicitly set `ColorFunction`.

So I wonder: Is it possible to change the default setting for the `ColorFunction`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, maybe you wanted to set `PlotStyle` instead?

Comment: You can use something like `SetOptions[Plot3D, {ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"}];` and now whenever you call `Plot3D` it will use that color function.  If you want the change to be more permanent (to persist after a kernel restart) then you need to add it to your `init.m` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `Plot3D` to look the way it used to, use the option `PlotTheme -> "Classic"`.

Compare the current output,

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

with what you get with the classic theme,

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to make that change permanent, then add the line

```
SetOptions[Plot3D, {PlotTheme -> "Classic"}]
```

to your [`init.m`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html) file.  You could also add color in other ways, with a `ColorFunction` as you mention, and you can store that option as the default using `SetOptions` as well.

Comment: Can you be more specific on which "init.m" file shall I add that options?(I'm using Kubuntu)

Comment: @ChuanChen Evaluate `SystemOpen[$UserBaseDirectory\Kernel\init.m]` and add it there